# Variable length nested list of lists pad shape

Tags: python, performance, array

Find shape of n-dim array that'd be formed from nested list of lists with variable lengths if we were to pad the lists to same length at each nest level. E.g.

```
ls = [[1],
      [2, 3],
      [4, 5, 6]]
# (3, 3) because
ls_padded = [[1, 0, 0],
             [2, 3, 0],
             [4, 5, 6]]
```

##### Attempt

```py
def find_shape(seq):
    try:
        len_ = len(seq)
    except TypeError:
        return ()
    shapes = [find_shape(subseq) for subseq in seq]
    return (len_,) + tuple(max(sizes) for sizes in
                           itertools.zip_longest(*shapes, fillvalue=1))
```

##### Problem

Too slow for large arrays. Can it be done faster? [Test & bench code](https://replit.com/@OverLordGoldDra/SpryFaintCgi#main.py).

Solution shouldn't require list values at final nest depth, only basic attributes (e.g. `len`), as that depth in application contains 1D arrays on GPU (and accessing values moves them back to CPU). It must work on **n-dim arrays**.

**Exact goal** is to attain such padding, but with choice of padding from left or from right. The data structure is a list of lists that's to form a 5D array, and only the final nest level contains non-lists, which are 1D arrays. First two nest levels have fixed list lengths (can directly form array), and the 1D arrays are of same length, so the only uncertainty is on 3rd and 4th dims.

Comment: Is there a reason you're seemingly rewriting [basic NumPy functionality](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.shape.html) here? Why not use NumPy to manage your arrays? How large/layers deep are you dealing with? Could you write a class abstraction that stores the length upon construction? I can say right off the bat that `(len_,) + tuple(...)` allocates 2 unnecessary objects that just go straight to the garbage collector after the concatenation but this seems like a micro-optimization given that depth would be unlikely to be huge, I'd imagine.

Comment: Given that if you know nothing about the sequence, you'll have to check every element recursively, you can't do better algorithmicly speaking. You could maybe optimize the implementation but not much.

Comment: @ggorlen End goal is to create the padded n-dim array as described, except need freedom to pad from left or right. I have the full function and `find_shape` is the bottleneck, especially when ran on GPU. Numpy can only create ragged, and not on GPU; Pytorch is used. If you have something in mind for this goal, I can open a question.

Comment: What do you mean with "Solution shouldn't require list values, only basic attributes"? You can't check a value's attributes without the value.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode `len(x)` doesn't require knowing `x[0]`

Comment: Right, but it requires knowing `x`. And you don't know whether `x` is a list until you look at it. Same for `x[0]`. You need to look at it anyway, because it could be a list. Btw, is that "Solution shouldn't require list values" paragraph part of the "Problem" section, i.e., you're saying your solution *does* have that problem, i.e., it does "require list values"? Or is that paragraph an epilogue to the question, not intended to describe a problem with your solution?

Comment: Hmm... is it guaranteed that all *numbers* are at the same depth and that there are no lists at that depth? Or could there be cases like `[1, [2, 3]]` or `[4, [], 5]`? And can there be empty lists (your `fillvalue=1` somewhat suggests "no")?

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode Updated. Yes, it's guaranteed, and no empties.

Comment: Ok, that allows much optimization. So it's guaranteed 5D and only third and fourth are unknown? That would also allow simpler code, and in that case it would help if your Test & bench code reflected that (that's excellent stuff, btw, I wish every question was that helpful :-), so that solutions making those assumptions would work there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question:

> The data structure is a list of lists that's to form a 5D array, and only the final nest level contains non-lists, which are 1D arrays. First two nest levels have fixed list lengths (can directly form array), and the 1D arrays are of same length, so the only uncertainty is on 3rd and 4th dims.

From your comment:

> and no empties

We can make it much faster by taking advantage of that specification.

Your solution walks over *everything*. Including the numbers, at the recursion leafs. Even always catching exceptions there, and ["catching an exception is expensive"](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html#how-fast-are-exceptions)

Instead, for the fixed-size dimensions just take the first length, and for the others run over all their lists and take the maximum length.

```
from itertools import chain

def find_shape_new(seq):
    flat = chain.from_iterable
    return (
        len(seq),
        len(seq[0]),
        max(map(len, flat(seq))),
        max(map(len, flat(flat(seq)))),
        len(seq[0][0][0][0]),
    )
```

(Only partially tested, as your Test & bench code doesn't adhere to your specification.)

Could also be generalized, maybe like this:

```
def find_shape_new(seq, num_dims=None, fixed_dims=None):
    ...
```

Parameters:

- `fixed_dims` would be a set naming the fixed dimensions. Like `{0, 1, 4}` or `{1, 2, 5}` for your specification above. For each fixed dimension, the function would use the `len(seq[0][0][0][0])` way, and for each non-fixed dimension, it would use the `max(map(len, flat(flat(seq))))` way.
- `num_dims` would tell the dimensionality, e.g., for a 5D array it would be 5. If unknown, represented by `None`, you'd just keep going until you reach a number instead of a list. That would involve looking at a number, but only at one.

Comment: So basically take short route for dims 0, 1, 4 and apply a faster `find_shape_old` on the rest? It's what I had in mind but hoped there's better, though it may very well be that better isn't needed - will test this

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon That, plus not looking at dim 5. It should be a lot better. Looking forward to your results. This is visiting almost only what needs to be visited, so I don't see how you'd hope for something better.

Comment: I omitted the simplifying parts to avoid "divide and conquer" solutions, instead focusing on the irreducible worst-case. Perhaps exhaustive iteration is the only way, which shifts optimization to parallelization. Your answer includes things I didn't think of, and I like that it can easily target the fixed dims, so I'll take it.

Answer (score 1):

Get the length of the longest row, then pad each row with a sufficient number of zeros.

```
from itertools import islice, repeat, chain


def pad(x):
    zeros = repeat(0)
    n = maximum(map(len, x))
    return [list(islice(chain(row, zeros), n)) for row in x]
```

`zeros` is an "infinite" stream of 0s. It doesn't actually store them in memory, but the instance of `repeat` defines a `__next__` method that always returns 0.

`chain` just glues two iterators together, so `chain(row, zeros)` will first yield the elements of `row`, then elements from `zeros`.

`islice(..., n)` yields the first `n` elements of the given iterator. How many zeros it will yield from `chain(row, zeros)` thus depends on how long `row` is in the first place.

Visually, you are constructing a sequence of infinite
rows, then taking finite prefixes from each. That is

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ... ] -> [1, 0, 0]
[2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, ... ] -> [2, 3, 0]
[4, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0, ... ] -> [4, 5, 6]
```

The list comprehension then just puts each row in a single list to complete the new array.

Comment: Isn't this only for 2D? I specified n-dim in opening sentence and test code, maybe I should've been more explicit

Comment: Oops, I did miss the n-dim request.

Comment: I'll upvote but keep question open - clarified